# R populate list by its values

Tags: r, list, for-loop, sapply

Say I have a list:

```
> fs
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] 61.90298 58.29699 54.90104 51.70293 48.69110
```

I want to "reverse fill" the rest of the list by using it's values. Example:

The `[[3]]` should have the function value of `[[4]]` pairs:

```
c( myFunction(fs[[4]][1], fs[[4]][2]), myFunction(fs[[4]][2], fs[[4]][3]), .... )
```

The `[[2]]` should have `myFunction` values of `[[3]]` etc...

I hope that's clear. What's the right way to do it? For loops? *applys? My last attempt, which leaves `1-3` empty:

```
n = length(fs)
for (i in rev(1:(n-1)))
  child_fs = fs[[i+1]]
  res = c()
  for (j in 1:(i+1))
    up = v(child_fs[j])
    do = v(child_fs[j+1])
    this_f = myFunction(up, do)
    res[j] = this_f
  fs[[i]] = res
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you show the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `fs` easily reproducible

```
fs <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL, c(61.90298, 58.29699, 54.90104, 51.70293, 48.69110))
```

To be able to show an example, make a trivial `myFunction`

```
myFunction <- function(a, b) {a + b}
```

You can loop over all but the last positions in `fs` (in reverse order), and compute each. Just call `myFunciton` with the vectors which are the next higher position's vectors without the last and without the first element.

```
for (i in rev(seq_along(fs))[-1]) {
  fs[[i]] <- myFunction(head(fs[[i+1]], -1), tail(fs[[i+1]], -1))
}
```

That assumes `myFunction` is vectorized (given vectors for inputs, will give a vector for output). If it isn't, you can easily make a version which is.

```
myFunction <- function(a, b) {a[[1]] + b[[1]]}

for (i in rev(seq_along(fs))[-1]) {
  fs[[i]] <- Vectorize(myFunction)(head(fs[[i+1]], -1), tail(fs[[i+1]], -1))
}
```

In either case, you get

```
> fs
[[1]]
[1] 453.2 426.8

[[2]]
[1] 233.398 219.802 206.998

[[3]]
[1] 120.200 113.198 106.604 100.394

[[4]]
[1] 61.90298 58.29699 54.90104 51.70293 48.69110
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, what you have is a starting point

```
start <- c(61.90298, 58.29699, 54.90104, 51.70293, 48.69110)
```

a function you want to apply (I made this one up which adds 1 everywhere and deletes the last element)

```
myFunction <- function(x) head(x + 1, -1L)
```

and the number of times you want to apply the function (recursively):

```
n <- 3L
```

So I would write a function to apply the function `n` times recursively, then reverse the output list:

```
apply.n.times <- function(fun, n, x)
   if (n == 0L) list(x) else c(list(x), Recall(fun, n - 1L, fun(x)))

rev(apply.n.times(myFunction, n, start))

# [[1]]
# [1] 64.90298 61.29699
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 63.90298 60.29699 56.90104
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 62.90298 59.29699 55.90104 52.70293
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 61.90298 58.29699 54.90104 51.70293 48.69110
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution (if myFunction can be replaced with something like sum, or in this case rowSums):

```
Reduce( function(x,y) rowSums( embed(y,2) ), fs, right=TRUE, accumulate=TRUE )
```

If myFunction needs to accept 2 values and do something with them then this can be expanded a bit to:

```
Reduce( function(x,y) apply( embed(y,2), 1, function(z) myFunction(z[1],z[2]) ), 
    fs, right=TRUE, accumulate=TRUE )
```